# Tiling with dynamic tile height and browser width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a tiling view built upon LI tags, where the amount of tiles per row and the height of each tile is dynamic. Also the tiling height, position and amount is dynamic while the list is already open and I do not want a fix row height because that would look bad and waste space. However the tiling height does not varry alot and for a good overview, I want all tiles of a row to have the same top offset.

Of course this is no big deal, when I add an LI after each row like so:

```
<li style="clear:both;opacity:0;height:0;"></li>
```

Of course the rules would be in a class.

[Here's a screenshot of how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4K2I.png)

[This is, how it currently looks due to the missing clearance LI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEUb2.png)

The solution in my mind is, after each change to the view, do the following:
- remove all elements with the clearance class
- $.each cycle all elements and insertBefore when the top position increases

However I'm afraid / pretty sure that the view will blink / look scrambled on each render change due to the fact that I have to remove all "clearance"-LI's first (otherwise I'd have row breaks where they possibly don't belong). This would especially look horribly wrong when resizing the browser width, for example. Or when a new tile is being added dynamically (new product in stock).

What should I do best to avoid this?
Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: Share your code, html and css, so that it will be easy to work on.

Comment: It's pretty hardwired into the depths of the system's OOP code - which I can't just post here for copyright reasons. I'll try to smack the problematic concept into smaller code as soon as I'll get to it. All the code that has nothing to do with the problem would just confuse people anyway.